# How to resume a big file download in winscp from a fixed position

Tags: get, sftp, winscp

I want to know how to resume a big file download instantly using get command using winscp command line. I want to download a 30gb file out of which 22 gb is already completed. Now when I am resuming transfer it’s not starting instantly and after some time server is sending disconnect because of which not able to resume file transfer in get command. Please let me know if any setting is there in which I can instantly resume file transfer from last position of the downloaded file.

Below is the session log :

```
. 2020-12-08 13:50:42.255 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2020-12-08 13:50:42.256 WinSCP Version 5.7.5 (Build 5665) (OS 6.3.9600 - Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard)
. 2020-12-08 13:50:42.257 Configuration: xx.ini
. 2020-12-08 13:50:42.258 Log level: Normal
. 2020-12-08 13:50:42.258 Local account: xx
. 2020-12-08 13:50:42.258 Working directory: xx
. 2020-12-08 13:50:42.258 Process ID: 33036
. 2020-12-08 13:50:42.258 Command-line: "xx\WinSCP.exe" /console=575 /consoleinstance=_26888_888 "/script=xx.txt" "/log=xx.log"
. 2020-12-08 13:50:42.258 Time zone: Current: GMT+5:30 (India Standard Time), No DST
. 2020-12-08 13:50:42.258 Login time: Tuesday, December 8, 2020 1:50:42 PM
. 2020-12-08 13:50:42.258 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2020-12-08 13:50:42.258 Script: Retrospectively logging previous script records:
> 2020-12-08 13:50:42.258 Script: option batch abort
< 2020-12-08 13:50:42.258 Script: batch           abort    
< 2020-12-08 13:50:42.258 Script: reconnecttime   120      
> 2020-12-08 13:50:42.258 Script: option confirm off
< 2020-12-08 13:50:42.258 Script: confirm         off      
> 2020-12-08 13:50:42.258 Script: open sftp://xx:xx@xxxxxx:xxxx -hostkey="ssh-rsa xx" -privatekey=xx.ppk -passphrase=xx -rawsettings Interface\SessionReopenAuto=40000000 SendBuf=0 SshSimple=0 -timeout=240
. 2020-12-08 13:50:42.258 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2020-12-08 13:50:42.258 Session name:xxx@xxx (Ad-Hoc site)
. 2020-12-08 13:50:42.258 Host name:xx(Port: xx)
. 2020-12-08 13:50:42.259 User name: xx (Password: Yes, Key file: Yes)
. 2020-12-08 13:50:42.259 Tunnel: No
. 2020-12-08 13:50:42.259 Transfer Protocol: SFTP
. 2020-12-08 13:50:42.259 Ping type: -, Ping interval: 30 sec; Timeout: 240 sec
. 2020-12-08 13:50:42.259 Disable Nagle: No
. 2020-12-08 13:50:42.259 Proxy: none
. 2020-12-08 13:50:42.259 Send buffer: 0
. 2020-12-08 13:50:42.259 SSH protocol version: 2; Compression: No
. 2020-12-08 13:50:42.259 Bypass authentication: No
. 2020-12-08 13:50:42.259 Try agent: Yes; Agent forwarding: No; TIS/CryptoCard: No; KI: Yes; GSSAPI: No
. 2020-12-08 13:50:42.259 Ciphers:X
. 2020-12-08 13:50:42.259 KEX: xx
. 2020-12-08 13:50:42.259 SSH Bugs: xxx
. 2020-12-08 13:50:42.259 Simple channel: No
. 2020-12-08 13:50:42.259 Return code variable: Autodetect; Lookup user groups: A
. 2020-12-08 13:50:42.259 Shell: default
. 2020-12-08 13:50:42.259 EOL: 0, UTF: 2
. 2020-12-08 13:50:42.259 Clear aliases: Yes, Unset nat.vars: Yes, Resolve symlinks: Yes
. 2020-12-08 13:50:42.259 LS: ls -la, Ign LS warn: Yes, Scp1 Comp: No
. 2020-12-08 13:50:42.259 SFTP Bugs: A,A
. 2020-12-08 13:50:42.259 SFTP Server: default
. 2020-12-08 13:50:42.259 Local directory: default, Remote directory: home, Update: Yes, Cache: Yes
. 2020-12-08 13:50:42.259 Cache directory changes: Yes, Permanent: Yes
. 2020-12-08 13:50:42.259 DST mode: 1
. 2020-12-08 13:50:42.259 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2020-12-08 13:50:42.260 Looking up host "xx"
. 2020-12-08 13:50:42.260 Connecting to xx port xxxx
. 2020-12-08 13:50:45.578 Server version: SSH-2.0-SFTP Server
. 2020-12-08 13:50:45.578 Using SSH protocol version 2
. 2020-12-08 13:50:45.578 We claim version: SSH-2.0-WinSCP_release_5.7.5
. 2020-12-08 13:50:47.299 Doing Diffie-Hellman group exchange
. 2020-12-08 13:50:51.570 Doing Diffie-Hellman key exchange with hash SHA-256
. 2020-12-08 13:50:53.394 Verifying host key rsa2 xxx
. 2020-12-08 13:50:53.397 Host key matches configured key
. 2020-12-08 13:50:53.397 Host key fingerprint is:
. 2020-12-08 13:50:53.397 xxxx
. 2020-12-08 13:50:53.397 Initialised AES-256 SDCTR client->server encryption
. 2020-12-08 13:50:53.397 Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 client->server MAC algorithm
. 2020-12-08 13:50:55.666 Initialised AES-256 SDCTR server->client encryption
. 2020-12-08 13:50:55.666 Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 server->client MAC algorithm
. 2020-12-08 13:50:57.262 Reading private key file "xx.ppk"
! 2020-12-08 13:50:57.265 Using username "xx".
. 2020-12-08 13:50:59.893 Offered public key
. 2020-12-08 13:51:02.047 Offer of public key accepted
! 2020-12-08 13:51:02.047 Authenticating with public key "xx"
. 2020-12-08 13:51:02.048 Prompt (passphrase, "SSH key passphrase", <no instructions>, "Passphrase for key "xx": ")
. 2020-12-08 13:51:02.048 Using configured passphrase.
. 2020-12-08 13:51:02.348 Sent public key signature
! 2020-12-08 13:51:03.280 Further authentication required
. 2020-12-08 13:51:03.280 Further authentication required
. 2020-12-08 13:51:03.280 Prompt (password, "SSH password", <no instructions>, "&Password: ")
. 2020-12-08 13:51:03.280 Using stored password.
. 2020-12-08 13:51:03.281 Sent password
. 2020-12-08 13:51:04.034 Access granted
. 2020-12-08 13:51:04.034 Opening session as main channel
. 2020-12-08 13:51:04.382 Opened main channel
. 2020-12-08 13:51:05.251 Started a shell/command
. 2020-12-08 13:51:05.252 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2020-12-08 13:51:05.252 Using SFTP protocol.
. 2020-12-08 13:51:05.255 Doing startup conversation with host.
> 2020-12-08 13:51:05.256 Type: SSH_FXP_INIT, Size: 5, Number: -1
< 2020-12-08 13:51:05.717 Type: SSH_FXP_VERSION, Size: 33, Number: -1
. 2020-12-08 13:51:05.718 SFTP version 3 negotiated.
. 2020-12-08 13:51:05.718 Unknown server extension  xx.com="\n"
. 2020-12-08 13:51:05.718 We believe the server has signed timestamps bug
. 2020-12-08 13:51:05.718 We will use UTF-8 strings until server sends an invalid UTF-8 string as with SFTP version 3 and older UTF-8 string are not mandatory
. 2020-12-08 13:51:05.718 Getting current directory name.
. 2020-12-08 13:51:05.718 Getting real path for '.'
> 2020-12-08 13:51:05.718 Type: SSH_FXP_REALPATH, Size: 10, Number: 16
< 2020-12-08 13:51:07.387 Type: SSH_FXP_NAME, Size: 51, Number: 16
. 2020-12-08 13:51:07.388 Real path is '/'
. 2020-12-08 13:51:07.388 Startup conversation with host finished.
< 2020-12-08 13:51:07.388 Script: Active session: [1] xx@xx
> 2020-12-08 13:51:07.390 Script: cd /xx
. 2020-12-08 13:51:07.390 Cached directory change via "/xx" to "/xx".
. 2020-12-08 13:51:07.390 Getting current directory name.
< 2020-12-08 13:51:07.390 Script: /xx
> 2020-12-08 13:51:07.391 Script: lcd xxx
< 2020-12-08 13:51:07.391 Script: xxx
> 2020-12-08 13:51:07.391 Script: get -resume -resumesupport=on -speed=256  xxx.xxx
. 2020-12-08 13:51:07.392 Listing file "xxx.xxx".
> 2020-12-08 13:51:07.392 Type: SSH_FXP_LSTAT, Size: 49, Number: 263
< 2020-12-08 13:51:09.121 Type: SSH_FXP_ATTRS, Size: 37, Number: 263
. 2020-12-08 13:51:09.121 xxx.xxx;-;30776595278;2020-12-04T11:07:14.000Z;"" [200];"" [100];rw-------;0
. 2020-12-08 13:51:09.121 Copying 1 files/directories to local directory "C:\H2H\MMSD"
. 2020-12-08 13:51:09.121   PrTime: Yes; PrRO: No; Rght: rw-r--r--; PrR: No (No); FnCs: N; RIC: 0100; Resume: Y (102400); CalcS: No; Mask:
. 2020-12-08 13:51:09.121   TM: B; ClAr: No; RemEOF: No; RemBOM: No; CPS: 262144; NewerOnly: No; InclM: ; ResumeL: 0
. 2020-12-08 13:51:09.121   AscM: *.*html; *.htm; *.txt; *.php; *.php3; *.cgi; *.c; *.cpp; *.h; *.pas; *.bas; *.tex; *.pl; *.js; .htaccess; *.xtml; *.css; *.cfg; *.ini; *.sh; *.xml
. 2020-12-08 13:51:09.121 File: '/xx/xxx.xxx' [2020-12-04T11:07:14.000Z] [30776595278]
. 2020-12-08 13:51:09.122 Copying "/xx/xxx.xxx" to local directory started.
. 2020-12-08 13:51:09.122 Binary transfer mode selected.
. 2020-12-08 13:51:09.123 Checking existence of partially transfered file.
. 2020-12-08 13:51:09.123 Partially transfered file exists.
. 2020-12-08 13:51:09.123 Resuming file transfer.
. 2020-12-08 13:51:09.124 Opening remote file.
> 2020-12-08 13:51:09.124 Type: SSH_FXP_OPEN, Size: 57, Number: 515
< 2020-12-08 13:51:10.570 Type: SSH_FXP_HANDLE, Size: 10, Number: 515
> 2020-12-08 13:51:10.571 Type: SSH_FXP_FSTAT, Size: 10, Number: 776
< 2020-12-08 13:51:11.353 Type: SSH_FXP_ATTRS, Size: 37, Number: 776
> 2020-12-08 13:51:11.353 Type: SSH_FXP_READ, Size: 22, Number: 1029
. 2020-12-08 13:53:18.497 Received disconnect message (by application)
. 2020-12-08 13:53:18.497 Disconnection message text: Idle connection
. 2020-12-08 13:53:18.497 Server sent disconnect message
. 2020-12-08 13:53:18.497 type 11 (by application):
. 2020-12-08 13:53:18.497 "Idle connection"
. 2020-12-08 13:53:18.498 Connection was lost, asking what to do.
. 2020-12-08 13:53:18.498 Asking user:
. 2020-12-08 13:53:18.498 Server sent disconnect message
. 2020-12-08 13:53:18.498 type 11 (by application):
. 2020-12-08 13:53:18.498 "Idle connection" ()
< 2020-12-08 13:53:18.498 Script: Server sent disconnect message
< 2020-12-08 13:53:18.498 type 11 (by application):
< 2020-12-08 13:53:18.498 "Idle connection"’
```

Comment: *"Now when I am resuming transfer it’s not starting instantly and after some time server is sending disconnect because of which not able to resume file transfer in get command"* – Can you elaborate on this? Why would "fixed position" help you to overcome that problem?

Comment: When I run the get command with resume parameter for this file , it’s taking some time to start download , by which time am recieving server sent disconnect message type 11 error .

Comment: Please post a session log file for that. + You didn't answer my other question.

Comment: I have edited the question to include session log. Sorry for the formatting. And you are right fixed position may not help me to overcome the problem.

Comment: Full log file please

Comment: Added full log in question

Answer (score 0):

As you are using some uncommon SFTP server, I guess the problem is that it does not support transfers that do not start at the beginning of the file.